# JavaScript click enter call button submit using Asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have created this javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function handle(e)
   {
    if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13)
     alert("The enter was pressed");
    }

</script>
```

And I have few text box, which I expected when I click enter, I will call button submit.

```
<asp:Textbox id="txtClient" Runat="Server" Width="252px"/>
<asp:Textbox id="txtDescription" Runat="Server" Width="252px"/>

<asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Height="22px" Text="Enter" Width="100px" />
```

But I still cannot display the message box, can someone show me how to handle and call button submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/xgxxp6ct/)**

```
$('input').on('keypress',function(e){
    if(e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
        alert('hit');
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Add this in your text box and call a function:

```
<asp:Textbox id="txtClient" Runat="Server" Width="252px" onkeypress="checkEnter(event)"/>

function checkEnter(ev)
{
        if(ev.which == 10 || ev.which == 13) {
        alert('hit');
    }
}
```

Comment: nope its not working either, is it because im using asp:textbox?

Comment: No probs.. anyways.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).keypress(function(e) {
         if(e.keyCode == 13) {
         alert("The enter was pressed");
        });

    </script>
```

try this...

Comment: im sorry but its not working. did I need to add anything for the text box?

Comment: and keep sending me up to my main page.which is quiet confusing to me